# Command to query services

Tags: powershell

I wrote a powershell command to audit services in HyperV HV's and

```
$Auditservices = get-service -computername $ComputerName -name "*iscsi*","*winrm*","*scvmm*","*vmms*","vss"| Select-Object Status, Name, MachineName
```

And output for the same is showing like below
MSiSCSI SCVMMAgent vmms vss WinRM Running Running Running Running Running

```
Is there anyway we can change the output to this format ?
MSiSCSI,Running 
SCVMMAgent,Running 
vmms,Running 
vss,Running 
WinRM,Running
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to get output exactly as you've described, you'll need to create some strings:

```
$Auditservices | Foreach-Object {"$($_.Name),$($_.Status)"}
```

You might instead actually want it in CSV format? If so, pipe it to [`Export-CSV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks alot